# How to persist entire operating system of Docker container

Tags: docker

Assuming I have a case of creating a Docker container with Ubuntu and giving RDP or VNC access to it to user. I need to persist ENTIRE user's system on /mnt/somevolume on the host system, so the next time container is starting (even if container is removed and created again or this /mnt/somevolume moved to another machine and user connects to that machine) user shall see the same state of operating system as it was left (including all his files, configs, background image, etc).

How can I achieve such thing?

Comment: A container is a temporary wrapper around a single process; what process is the container running?  Would a virtual machine with a normal operating system better fit your needs?

Comment: @DavidMaze unfortunately not. There is a requirement to use docker